# Can't install 15.10 Server

Tags: server

I'm unable to install either the 15.10 or 14.04 server on 2 of my pc's. One is an older amd and the other is a new intel nuc. in both cases i get to the language selection screen and the install freezes.

I've read various people having this problem for some years but no solution seems to work for me.

Any ideas?

Thank You

Comment: Your image from which you are trying to boot seems to be corrupt. You might want to create it again and retry.

Comment: Thanks. I've downloaded it onto ubuntu desktop on both machines and have created usb installs on both machines. Unless both installation downloads are corrupt I dont think that is the problem.

Comment: What did you use to make the USBs?

Comment: Tried everything on both machines. Startup disk vreator, netbootin, disks. All have the same results from both machines

Comment: Just prior to the language selection screen appearing, the following message appears: Mounting /dev/sda on /media failed - invalid argument

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems.
You can try downloading the image again
changing the usb stick
burning the image onto a cd
or if you can try using Universal USB Installer (Has worked for me)